# adal4j Auth issue

Tags: azure, adal, adal4j

Hi i wrote a deamon app that uses Microsoft active directory, the app works fine in development environment but in production (AWS EC2 instance) i get this error :

```
java.lang.Exception: Server returned error in RSTR - ErrorCode: FailedAuthentication : FaultMessage: MSIS7068 : accès refusé.
        at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.WSTrustResponse.parse(WSTrustResponse.java:103) ~[adal4j-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
        at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.WSTrustRequest.execute(WSTrustRequest.java:69) ~[adal4j-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
        at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.processPasswordGrant(AuthenticationContext.java:790) ~[adal4j-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
        at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.access$000(AuthenticationContext.java:63) ~[adal4j-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
        at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext$1.call(AuthenticationContext.java:129) [adal4j-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
        at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext$1.call(AuthenticationContext.java:119) [adal4j-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]

2018-07-19 08:40:02.829 ERROR 5072 --- [nio-8083-exec-1] f.a.agent.reservation.utils.OAuth        : java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.Exception: Server returned error in RSTR - ErrorCode: FailedAuthentication : FaultMessage: MSIS7068 : accès refusé.
```

I dont understand what's going on here because Dev and Prod envs are ISO.

This is the class that connects to active directory :

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

import com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext;
import com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationResult;


import lombok.extern.java.Log;

@Log
public class OAuth {
    private static String TOKEN = null;
    private final static String AUTHORITY_URL = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/";
    private final static String GRAPH_URL = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
    private final static String CLIENT_ID = "*****";
    private final static String USERNAME = "*****";
    private final static String PASSWORD = "*****";

    public static final String getToken() throws Exception {
        if (null == TOKEN) {
            AuthenticationContext context;
            AuthenticationResult result = null;
            ExecutorService service = null;
            log.info("Auth with : " + USERNAME);
            try {
                service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
                context = new AuthenticationContext(AUTHORITY_URL, false, service);
                Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken(GRAPH_URL, CLIENT_ID, USERNAME, PASSWORD, null);
                result = future.get();
            }catch (Exception e){
                log.severe(e.toString());
            } finally {
                service.shutdown();
            }

            if (result == null) {
                log.severe("AUTH FAILLURE");
            } else {
                TOKEN = result.getAccessToken();
            }
        }
        return TOKEN;
    }



}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Providing **configuration details** (for both ADAL and AD/AAD) and code snippets that cause the exception will also be really helpful. Otherwise your question simply doesn't make sense.

Comment: i just edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the origin of this problem by trying to connect using a refresh token obtained from my company's network.

```
"error_description":"AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'.\r\nTrace ID: xxxxx\r\nCorrelation ID: xxxxxx b\r\nTimestamp: 2018-07-20 12:34:45Z","error":"interaction_required"
```

So i understand that two factor auth is not required from inside my company's network but it is required outside of it.

I will have to contact the administrator of office 365 in my company to have special account to authenticate without two factor authentication.

Answer (score 0):

For the flow you are using (`resource owner password credential` - by directly providing user credentials) you have to use the tenant specific endpoint. Which means, you have to change:

```
private final static String AUTHORITY_URL = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/";
```

to

```
private final static String AUTHORITY_URL = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/";
```

Where you can use your either tenant domain (i.e. yourdomain.onmicrosoft.com) or the tenant_id in `<tenant_id>`.

Comment: Hi, i still got the same problem when i put  <tenant_id> or mydomain.onmicrosoft.com [java.lang.Exception: Server returned error in RSTR - ErrorCode: FailedAuthentication : FaultMessage: MSIS7068 : accès refusé.]

Comment: And the flow i'm using is (resource, clientId, username, password, callback), PS: everything works fine in dev environment the issue is just in prod env.